# Can you access `this` using the built-in NodeJS debugger?

Tags: node.js

I'm using http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

I put a breakpoint inside a method:

```
Processor.prototype.myMethod = function() {
  console.log(this.constructor.name);  // returns Processor

  debugger;

  this.otherMethod(123);
}
```

And I call `node debug myapp.js` and I reach the breakpoint. But when I type `this.constructor.name`, I get 'Object', not 'Processor'.

Can I access the `this` inside that scope or do I have to use something like https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector ?

**Edit:** I can't seem to access any script variables from the debugger, not even `Processor`. I'm using v0.10.13 on OS X.

Comment: A workaround might be `var self = this` and then accessing `self` in the debugger.

Comment: @ThiefMaster That doesn't seem to work: `ReferenceError: self is not defined`

Comment: Wouldn't work. Doing this would be useful only when going deeply in the same function scope, which doesn't seem to be the case because he's using `prototype` to create the class.

Comment: I meant putting it in your code before the `debugger` statement.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yes, that's what I did and that's the error I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access to the values from this, and any another value that are accessible from the scope where the debugger stopped, but you should start the debugger `repl`, typing that command in the same debugger, and then type there the value that you would like to watch (`this.constructor.name`).

To leave the debugger's repl, press `ctrl + c` and you will get back to the debugger prompt.

Remind you that you constructor will have a name if it is a named function if not it will be empty string, for example
`var Processor = function Processor() {};` instead of `var Processor = function () {};`,

Comment: Thanks! I guess I missed the [repl](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_info) command in the docs because I expected it to work immediately. I can see why that might not be a good idea, though.